# Change Status of Workflow Approval Process Task

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have added an Approval Process to a list workflow which is creating tasks in a separate task list.
When I approve or reject a task, the status of the particular task remains "In Progress".

- How can I change the task status in my workflow according to the
  chosen action?
- How can I lock the task, so that no user can approve or reject it
  anymore?

I am using Designer 2013 according to a Sharepoint 2013 but with the 2010 workflow engine.

Comment: Are you sure it is not displaying Workflow Stage in the SharePoint Designer? Or are you stating it is stuck at In progress?

Comment: In the task list itself, the workflow status remains "In Progress" after approving the item.